# Convert an Array to Json Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, backend

im getting this error

> ErrorException in helpers.php line 685:
>   preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array

i want to convert the comments entity, but i dont know how that will look.

whats the best choice? toJson() or json_encode?

this is my controller

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
    {
        $trip = Trip::find($id);  
        $trip = Trip::with('comments')->where('id', $id)->first();
        $trip->fill($request->input());

        if($request->has('comments')){
            // foreach($request->comments as $comments){
            //     $comments = Comment::find($id);
            //     $comments->fill($request->input());
            //     $comments->save();

                 $commentArray=[];
        foreach($request->comments as $key=>$commentEntity) {
            // dd($commentEntity);
            // dd($request->comments);
             $comment =Comment::find($id);
            $comment->comment=$commentEntity['comment'];
            $comment->trip_id=$commentEntity['trip_id'];
            $comment->date=date('Y,m,d,G,i,s');
            $comment->user_id=$commentEntity['user_id'];
            $comment->save();
            }
        }



       if($request->files){
        foreach($request->files as $files){
            $file = File::find($id);
            $file->save();
            }       
     } 

        $trip->save();
        return response()->json($trip);

    }
```

I already try with :

```
            **// $strFromArr = serialize($comment); and
            // $comment->toJson(); and this way too
            //$json = json_encode($comment);**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @omadonex said, there is no need to convert the model before returning it from the controller.
In Laravel's controllers you can just return model/collection and Laravel will take care of the conversions.

I don't think that the `return $trip;` was preventing your data to be updated - so I suggest you to make the change and re-debug your code.

For your comments update, add comment id to every row that you send and use this foreach:

```
foreach($request->comments as $commentEntity) {
    $comment = Comment::find($commentEntity['id']);
    $comment->comment = $commentEntity['comment'];
    $comment->trip_id = $commentEntity['trip_id'];
    $comment->date = date('Y,m,d,G,i,s');
    $comment->user_id = $commentEntity['user_id'];
    $comment->save();
}
```

Comment: how would that will look? $comment are a completely apart table from trip, but trip has that comment.

Comment: You try to find a comment with the id of the request - which seems like the id of the trip. Try to create the comment with the trip model `$trip->comments()->create(['comment' => X, 'date' => Y, 'user_id' => Z])`

Comment: but that creates a new comment right? or it works too for update?

Comment: It will just create, do you need to create, update or both?

Comment: actually i need both, and in the same form, and i dont know how to achieve that, but thats for later, im trying to fix this error, dont saving data in db. 
its an update function if you see. How could apply the solution you gave me in update?

Comment: Im on that right now. Does it need the return after the foreach?

Comment: It depends if you need the data in the response... Putting return or not won't affect your update

Comment: didnt work :( and i did it like you say and with return

Comment: Did you add the comment id field to the post data of the request?

Comment: when i remove the return it throws the same error 
ErrorException in helpers.php line 685: preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array

Comment: Can you add the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: in helpers.php line 685
at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\zignyWS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php', '685', array('search' => '\?', 'replace' => array('444', '0110', 'FORT KENT', array(array('id' ....

Comment: Do you have to full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: excuse me for this question but, from where i can get that full stack trace ? is it the error message?

Comment: its like 6k lines of code :| what part of it do you need?

Comment: Delete the file, make the request, and copy the new text - it won't be so much

Comment: Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'preg_replace():...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 685, Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\zignyWS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php(685): preg_replace('/\\?/', Array, 'update `w8_w8sh...', 1)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\zignyWS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\QueryException.php(56): str_replace_array('\\?', Array, 'update `w8_w8sh...')

Comment: That's the error! I just need the lines below which explains from where the exception came from. From this line I can see that it's an DB error

Comment: 3 C:\xampp\htdocs\zignyWS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\QueryException.php(39): Illuminate\Database\QueryException->formatMessage('update `w8_w8sh...', Array, Object(PDOException))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\zignyWS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(667): Illuminate\Database\QueryException->__construct('update `w8_w8sh...', Array, Object(PDOException))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\zignyWS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(622): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('update `w8_w...

Whats the error?

Comment: Still, I can't tell, clear the log and copy all the lines, I need to see untill at least row 15-20

Comment: #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\zignyWS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(416): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('update `w8_w8sh...', Array, Object(Closure))
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\zignyWS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(359): Illuminate\Database\Connection->affectingStatement('update `w8_w8sh...', Array)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\zignyWS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php(1858): Illuminate\Database\Connection->update('update `w8_w8sh...', Array)

Comment: #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\zignyWS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php(384): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->update(Array)
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\zignyWS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1526): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->update(Array)
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\zignyWS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1445): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->performUpdate(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), Array)

Comment: 13 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\ShipmentController->update('43', Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\zignyWS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php(256): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)

Comment: #15 C:\xampp\htdocs\zignyWS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(164): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('update', Array)
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\zignyWS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(112): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(App\Http\Controllers\ShipmentController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'update')
#17 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

Comment: #19 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\zignyWS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(102): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)).

Comment: There! i hope you can help me

Comment: Line #12 is missing, and the only one that matters jaja

Comment: #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\zignyWS\app\Http\Controllers\ShipmentController.php(281): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->save()

Comment: ShipmentControl‌ler line 281! That's the line which causes the error! What line is it?

Comment: its the line at the end of the update function      } 

        $trip->save();
        return response()->json($trip);

    }

Comment: Maybe that's because you assign to the trip model all the input parameters which is not only the fields of the Trip model (`$trip->fill($request->input());`).. Which fields do you need to update?

Comment: all the fields, but i think the problem came with the comments but idk. what do you mean by the fields i need to update?   with the input() im assigning all the inputs of the form ?

Comment: Try to dump `$request->input()` and see what you get. If you see values which not belongs to the Trip model - use `$request->only(['field_a', 'field_b']``

Comment: I just tried like this  $shipment->fill() and it throws the same error... then i tried with the only way. like this  
 $trip->fill($request->only(['id','user_id', 'company_id', 'date', 'truckNumber','invoiceNumber','sequence','status','isDown','port','pedimento','carrier','carrierSCAC','conveyance','equipment','driver','arribalCountry','broker','portValue','extraField','dateUpdateStatus','dateProcess','shipmentExternalId','shipmentType','entryNumber','gpsIpAddress','trailerGpsIpAddress','truckGpsIpAddress','arrivalDateTime','preparerUserID','tripNumber']));
AND IT WOOORKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just simple it automatically converts any model to json if you return it

```
return $trip;
```

Comment: already tried it, it no longer show the error, but doesnt update the data in db.